# Jmeter- Reading Application log

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am running a jmeter test, POST submitting a request i need to check the application log(openshift) to find an application specific message/id is generated ,it need to be captured as its a test data for my subsequent request. Any solution is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your setup you can go for:

1. Normal [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) call to [`/api/v1/namespaces/$NAMESPACE/pods/$NAME/log`](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.7/rest_api/api/v1.Pod.html#Get-api-v1-namespaces-namespace-pods-name-log)
2. Run [`oc log` command](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/admin_guide/router.html#viewing-logs) using [OS Process Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) or [SSH Command](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler#ssh-command) sampler